# How to invert mouse control? (ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse

How can I do if I want a function that inverts mouse control, like when I want to go right, it goes left, and when i go up it goes down?

The only thing I thought about was mouseX = mouseY even if it's not what i wanted to do, but it doesn't even work so yeah, if you guys have a solution it would be great.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the mouseX and mouseY properties to force the location of the mouse pointer.

However, you can hide the mouse pointer and create a fake one.

```
Mouse.hide(); // hide the mouse pointer
```

Then you can just set that pointer's x,y to the opposite of the real one.

```
fakeMouse.x = mouseX * -1;
fakeMouse.y = mouseY * -1;
```

You might have to handle other cases as well, but that's the only concept that will get you close to achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any further details I just give a general answer:
if you mean within your operating system (windows, linux, mac,..) then you will have to set the os-properties or download a tool for it.
If you mean within a code, you will probably need a programing language that has access to the os functions such as c, c++. 
Here is an example:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/111952/how-do-you-invert-the-mouse-control